# How are terms connected with posts in database?

Tags: posts, database, taxonomy, terms

In a multi-site environment, I have a special need to get post terms (on a custom taxonomy) without the expensive operation of "switching blogs".

I thought I might write my own query to get terms for a given post on a given blog.

I'm looking through the three tables:

```
wp_3_terms
wp_3_term_relationships
wp_3_term_taxonomy
```

Yet I cannot see where there is a connection to post_id in any of these.

So the question:

How do terms link with a given post in the database? If I can know that, I can do the rest.

Answer (score 3):

The posts are related to taxonomies (taxonomy/tag) in the `wp_3_term_relationships` table, where the `object_id` column is the post's id, and the `term_taxonomy_id` is the taxonomy/tag id.

Depending on what you want to accomplish, the solution might be to create the same taxonomies at each blog. This way the `tax_query` should work as normal.